# Return number of discharges within a given period from remote JSON array

Tags: jquery, json

I have a search with from date and to date and a selectbox with departments.I want department wise discharges (count) within a given period from my remote JSON array and display in the HTML table.

This is my remote JSON array:

```
{
   "success":true,
   "dataList":[
      {
         "dischargedatetime":"2018-12-26T00:00:00",
         "DepartmentName":"Cardiology",
         "DischargeCount":3
      },
      {
         "dischargedatetime":"2018-12-25T00:00:00",
         "DepartmentName":"Cardiology",
         "DischargeCount":2
      },
      {
         "dischargedatetime":"2018-12-26T00:00:00",
         "DepartmentName":"Clinical Hematology",
         "DischargeCount":3
      }
   ]
}
```

And this is my URL:

```
getDepartmentwiseDischarge?startDate=2018-12-25&endDate=2018-12-26&departmentName=Cardiology
```

Comment: What generates your JSON data? It would be best to do the filtering based on date when querying

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach loop on json and bind to table like below.

```js
var json = [{
  "dischargedatetime": "2018-12-26T00:00:00",
  "DepartmentName": "Cardiology",
  "DischargeCount": 3
}, {
  "dischargedatetime": "2018-12-25T00:00:00",
  "DepartmentName": "Cardiology",
  "DischargeCount": 2
}, {
  "dischargedatetime": "2018-12-26T00:00:00",
  "DepartmentName": "Clinical Hematology",
  "DischargeCount": 3
}];

var DName = [],
  DCount = [];

json.forEach(function(obj) {
  if (DName.indexOf(obj.DepartmentName) == -1)
    DName.push(obj.DepartmentName);

  var lastIndex = DName.length - 1;
  if (typeof DCount[lastIndex] == "undefined")
    DCount.push(obj.DischargeCount);
  else
    DCount[lastIndex] += obj.DischargeCount;
});
Array.prototype.associate = function(keys) {
  var result = {};

  this.forEach(function(el, i) {
    result[keys[i]] = el;
  });

  return result;
};
var datalist = DName.associate(DCount); //Make key value par after sum
var html; //Generate html for table.
$.each(datalist, function(key, val) {
  html += "<tr>"
  html += "<td>" + val + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + key + "</td > ";
  html += "</tr>"

});
$('table').append(html);
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>DepartmentName</th>
    <th>DischargeCount</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I get the feeling OP wants to total the `DischargeCount` numbers per `DepartmentName` (I could be wrong though)

Comment: If op comment for that I edit my answer. Thanks for head up. @Phil

Comment: Sir i want the total count of discharges group by month

Comment: its not working with my code sir.Sir i want the total number of DischargeCount group by month with a given period and i am new with json

Comment: Try to debug your code. It's not working is not best comment. You see working example on snippet. Any console error ?